Magento 2 : Remove Magento backend Catalog Product search error? I need to search sku to edit listing in product catalog
Please help me, my magento backend has error in Catalog Products, I want to search SKU to edit listings. How to remove this error please? Thanks.

specify which error you are facing whiile searching the SKU?
